# Override a specific method of interface

Tags: go, interface, overriding

I want to implement a slightly customized version of an Interface. Let's take [sort.Interface](https://pkg.go.dev/sort#Interface) as an example. We already have [sort.IntSlice](https://pkg.go.dev/sort#IntSlice) that implements the whole interface. But I want to implement an AbsoluteSort algorithm. For that, I only want to change the `Less` method. Something like this:

```
type AbsSortedArray struct {
    sort.IntSlice
}

func (a AbsSortArray) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return abs(a[i]) < abs(a[j])      // this causes an error as I don't have access to underlying array here
}

func abs(i int) int {
    if i  < 0 {
        return i * -1
    }
    
    return i
}
```

So basically what I want to achieve is:

1. Inherit other methods like `Len` and `Swap` from the parent
2. Override `Less` method, **BUT** not with intent of *stubbing/mocking*, rather I want the access to the underlying object so that I can still implement my custom logic.

Comment: Hold on, please read the `Less` func I'm calling the `abs` function before returning the comparision

Comment: Note that these are not arrays and this is not method overriding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't have access to underlying array here

Actually, you do:

```golang
func (a AbsSortArray) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return abs(a.IntSlice[i]) < abs(a.IntSlice[j])
}
```

But this `AbsSortedArray` is a cumbersome data type to use (as now you must deal with a struct with a slice member, rather than using a slice directly). It would probably be much more readable and maintanable in this specific example to just provide your own from-scratch implementation.

Comment: I agree, I just wanted to know how can I access the underlying data, your response answered the question. The point is that I was just presenting this as an example use case. What if I have a bigger interface with 10+ methods, and my functionality just requires 1 or methods to be changed for a custom implementation.